# multidimensional array in awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have a small database as below:

```
    10/08/2011      laptop  4
    10/08/2011      laptop  2
    10/08/2011      desktop 2
    10/08/2011      laptop  1
    10/08/2011      pen     5
    10/08/2011      pen     2
    10/08/2011      waterbottle     8
    10/2/2011       ring    11
    10/02/2011      waterbottle     5
    10/2/2011       ring    2
    10/2/2011       ring    4
    10/2/2011       keyboard        20
    10/2/2011       keyboard        10
    11/2/2011       mouse   10
    11/2/2011       mouse   4
    11/2/2011       mouse   10
    11/2/2011       door    55
```

I wanted to count how many each of those items were sold on each day. I tried something with awk as below, but it fails...

```
awk '{arr[$1,$2]++;}END {for (i in  arr){ for (j in arr[$i]){print arr[$i,$j];}}}' data
```

Any ideas, how to do it ?? I will appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Awk arrays are mappings from keys to values. What you have produced by trying to get a multidimensional array is actually an array with more complex keys. Thus, you should iterate over the combined keys, not the indices that you used to build them:

```
awk '{ arr[$1,$2]++ } END {for (key in  arr){ print arr[key] } }' data
```

Comment: I concur strongly with this solution. There is no need for multi-dimensional anything to solve this problem and this is the proper iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with *GNU awk 4.0*:

```
awk 'END {
  for (D in d)
    for (E in d[D])
      print E, d[D][E]
  }
{ 
  d[$1][$2]++
  }' infile
```

In most cases the solution posted by *@Michael J. Barber* will be sufficient.

With *GNU awk 4.0* you can also easily order the values (in this example, ordered by quantity sold):

```
% awk 'END {
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
  for (D in d) {
    split(D, t, SUBSEP)
    print t[1], t[2], d[D]
    }
  }
{
  d[$1, $2]++
  }' infile  
11/2/2011 mouse 3
10/2/2011 ring 3
10/08/2011 laptop 3
10/2/2011 keyboard 2
10/08/2011 pen 2
10/08/2011 desktop 1
11/2/2011 door 1
10/08/2011 waterbottle 1
10/02/2011 waterbottle 1
```